# How to add signing Request Headers in Get Request for Cryptsy using C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, desktop-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have written a program for withdrawing coins from the Cryptsy.com. This program first converts the all parameters to the HMAC SHA512 and then this data has to be sent as signing information for Authentication. This signed data is required to be sent in headers. When i run this program it always shows the Error "Must be Authenticated". I had run the API on RestClient where i dont find this error. So i want to know why it is not working with the following code.

```
client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.cryptsy.com/");
int nonce = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        String msg = "nonce="+nonce+"&limit=100";
        msg = msg + "&quantity="+_amount+"&address="+_with_to+"&notificationtoken="+_notification_token;
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(encoding.GetBytes(_pri_key));
        byte[] getsigndata = hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(msg));
        string sbinary = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getsigndata.Length; i++)
        {
            sbinary += getsigndata[i].ToString("X2");
        }
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        HttpRequestMessage requestmessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/v2/withdraw/" + allCurrencies.Find(l => l.name == _with_from).id + "?" + msg);
        requestmessage.Headers.Add("key", _pub_key);
        requestmessage.Headers.Add("sign", sbinary);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestmessage).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            String reqdata = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(reqdata);
            String valu=obj["success"].ToString();
            Boolean isSuccess;
            if (valu == "False")
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            if(isSuccess)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                String[] err= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String[]>(obj["error"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(err[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }`
```

Comment: You could run both your working version and this version through a tool like Fiddler or Runscope and then compare the requests to see what is different.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your use of HttpClient.  Most likely there is some subtle difference in the way the sign header value is created.

Comment: I used to debug the code again and again in Visual Studio and all the time i collected data while debugging and run that in Rest Client. In Rest Client found right result for the same values.